# Can't post file using python requests - Translation from curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

The following command works, but I can't reproduce it using python-requests (2.18.4) :

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." \
             -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
             -F 'metadata={...} 
             -F 'data=@data.bz2;type=application/octet-stream' 
              https://www....com
```

Using the send_devices below, I receive "Unsupported Media Type""

```
def send_devices(basic_auth):
    endpoint_api = ' https://www....com'
    with open('data.bz2','rb') as payload:
        response = requests.post(endpoint_api, data={'metadata': ...,
                                                     'data': payload},
                                 headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(basic_auth})
```

After some comments, I also tried and the error now is "Invalid Metadata Json String":

```
def send_devices(basic_auth):
    endpoint_api = ' https://www....com'
    files = {'file': ('data.bz2', open('data.bz2', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}
    response = requests.post(endpoint_api, data={"metadata": {"extensions":{"urnType":"IDFA"}}},
                             files=files, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(basic_auth)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, was missing the file type

```
'data': ('data.bz2', open('data.bz2', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
```

In the second example, is necessary to add extra post data on the same files dict. Even if is not a dict:

```
'metadata': ('metadata.csv', json.dumps({"extensions": ...}))}
```

The solution:

```
def send_devices(basic_auth):
    endpoint_api = ' https://www....com'
    files = {'data': ('data.bz2', open('data.bz2', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
            'metadata': ('metadata.csv', json.dumps({"extensions": ...}))}
    response = requests.post(endpoint_api, files=files,
                             headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(basic_auth)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the payload is formatted correctly. It appears you are missing an '{' in your second object within your payload.

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but it is was only a typo when editing here...

Answer (score 1):

You should put it as file (not as data).

`r = requests.post(url, files={'file': open('data.bz2', 'rb')})`

works fine.

Comment: Yeah, actually i was also trying that, but the error is now "Invalid Metadata Json String". I edited the question.

Comment: Do this requests (curl and python) to https://httpbin.org/headers to see difference.

Comment: Great! Used that to debug and after a few tries, worked. will post an answer asap